# XML reading from REST API in RuleChain (Thingsboard)

Tags: thingsboard

I'm trying to read external data with REST API as in this tutorial.

https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/get-weather-using-rest-api-call/

The problem is that my server answers with XML text and not with a JSON payload.
For this reason, the (blue) Script node within RuleChain does not accept the input and I cannot parse the XML text.

Does anyone know how to get around the problem? Should I use some other node? Or is there no solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add 'Content-Type': xml to the headers? Or something along those lines?

Comment: Hi @JacksonB, thank you for you answer!
No, I cannot change the API output format... I was thinking to encapsulate the xml payload in a json payload but I would need a rulechain block to do that...